# Use Random URL instead of Fixed one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know much about JS or Jquery so any help is appreciated. Bascially I want to use random url instead of fixed one . A random url can be fetched from an external flat text file 
http://example.com/url100.txt

The current code that I am using inside the  section of the html page is as follow

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  var mylinks = "http://google.com";
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#default-usage .to-lock').sociallocker({

    buttons: {order:["facebook-like","twitter-tweet","google-plus"]},

    twitter: {url:"http://google.com"},
    facebook: {url:"http://google.com"},
    google: {url:"http://google.com"},

    text: {
      header: "Like us To Unlock This Content",
      message: "This content is locked. Like us on Twitter, Facebook or Google plus to unlock it."
    },

    locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},
    theme: "secrets"
  });
});
  //]]>
</script>
```

So basically instead of twitter: {url:"http://example.net"}, i want to use a random url. Hope I am clear with my question

Comment: You need in a first time to fetch your file, parse it and store data into a var lets named it `urls`. After that in your socialloker, `twitter: url[Math.floor((Math.random() * urls.length))]`

Comment: what is the format to store the url in text file `url100.txt`?

Comment: @Orel thanks but how do I fetch the url ? first ? Care to share the code snippet please

Comment: @jogesh_pi - The format is simple : one url in each new line

Comment: _“Like us To Unlock This Content”_ – at least Facebook does not allow like gating any more. Please go read their Platform Policies.

Comment: @Cbore - Thanks for the heads up. I do not intend to use FB anyway so I think i am still cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Make sure the file is on the same server.
var file = "http://example.com/url100.txt";
$.get(file,function(txt) {

    // Split data and convert it into array
    var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
    var link = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];

    // Apply plugin here
    $('#default-usage .to-lock').sociallocker({

        buttons: {order:["facebook-like","twitter-tweet","google-plus"]},
        twitter: {url:link},
        facebook: {url:link},
        google: {url:link},

        text: {
            header: "Like us To Unlock This Content",
            message: "This content is locked. Like us on Twitter, Facebook or Google plus to unlock it."
        },

        locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},
        theme: "secrets"
    });

});
```

As you said you have use it on BLOGSPOT, and text file exists on another server. Then use this solution.

### Solution 2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Add link one by one in ""
    var social_links = ["link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5", "link6"];

    var link = social_links[Math.floor(Math.random() * social_links.length)];
    console.log(link);
    // Apply plugin here
    $('#default-usage .to-lock').sociallocker({

        buttons: {order:["facebook-like","twitter-tweet","google-plus"]},
        twitter: {url:link},
        facebook: {url:link},
        google: {url:link},

        text: {
            header: "Like us To Unlock This Content",
            message: "This content is locked. Like us on Twitter, Facebook or Google plus to unlock it."
        },

        locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},
        theme: "secrets"
    });

});
```

Comment: Tried this code but it for some reason now the social locker is not displayed at all .                                                                                                                http://insta-downloads.blogspot.in/2015/02/check-test.html

Comment: the error is because you are accessing the data cross domain, your text file should be locate on same server.

Comment: Thanks again. Blogspot doesn't allow any file upload so I am kind of forced to use cross domain. Any solution ?

Comment: you can't access cross domain with ajax, another solution is you have you links in a variable and then apply on your plugin.

Comment: awesome. Can you please edit the code so i can have links in variable ?

Comment: I already edited, `var social_links` is a array that holds all the links, replace `link1` with your original links.

Comment: Tried the new code its not working http://insta-downloads.blogspot.in/2015/02/check-test.html

Comment: To bypass cross origin problems you have several options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: @mgutt - are you saying there is a way to use the first code provided by jogesh_pi ? if so can you please share the code snippet ?

Comment: Anybody willing to find out a way to achieve this ?

Comment: @PriyankaSharma Offering for help! And the reward?

Comment: @jogesh_pi - You are a pro, what reward can I offer you my friend. I can only wish that all your dreams are fulfilled.

Comment: @PriyankaSharma I don't need anything, anyway. now apply the **Solution 2**, i have updated, and let me know.

Comment: Awesome. Its working now . I hope soon you can find me a way to use external cross domain txt file :)

Comment: @PriyankaSharma cross domain you can access with PHP not javascript or jquery.

Comment: @jogesh_pi this is wrong. You can use JSONP or CORS as you can see in my posted link. A simple `<script src=...` works, too. Or is `url100.txt` not editable through Priyanka Sharma?

Comment: If he is not able to edit the file he could use http://www.whateverorigin.org as the very last option.